# Compatibility of ContainerResponseFilter in jersey 1.17

Tags: filter, jersey, containers, response, grizzly

Can i run my CustomFilter extended with ContainerResponseFilter in jersey1.17.
I am using GrizzlyWebServer. Please suggest . Given below is my sample server code to add the filter.

```
   GrizzlyWebServer webServer = new GrizzlyWebServer(.............);
    ....
    ....

    ServletAdapter adapter3 = new ServletAdapter();
    adapter3.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.motilink.server.services");
    adapter3.setContextPath("/");
    adapter3.setServletInstance(new ServletContainer());
    adapter3.addContextParameter(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS, PoweredbyResponseFilter.class.getName());
    webServer.addGrizzlyAdapter(adapter3, new String[]{"/"});

   ...
   .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS) property as a `init-param` and not as a `context-param`:

```
...
adapter3.addInitParameter(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS, PoweredbyResponseFilter.class.getName());
...
```

#### EDIT 1

From your answer it seems that you're actually trying to use Jersey 1.x (1.17) runtime with implemented JAX-RS 2.0 providers (`ContainerRequestContext` and `ContainerResponseContext` have been introduced in JAX-RS 2.0 and Jersey 1.x doesn't know how to use them).

So my advice would be - drop all your Jersey 1.17 dependencies and replace them with Jersey 2.x dependencies. Take a look at our [helloworld-webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-webapp) example (particularly at [App](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/helloworld-webapp/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/helloworld/webapp/App.java) class) to see how to create a Grizzly server instance with JAX-RS application.

Note that it is sufficient to add just [ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_PACKAGES) property to `init-param`s and your Resources and Providers (incl. response filters) will be scanned and registered in the application.

Comment: can u please  explain me !!

Comment: Your JAX-RS resources in `com.motilink.server.services` package work as expected? Do you see something in the server log?

Comment: no there is only the retrieved data in the server log!! not any error messages just the filter doesn't get executed. Is it due to using jersey v1.17 and javax.ws.rs-api.2.0?

Comment: Well, you certainly shouldn't be mixing those two. Use Jersey 1.x with JAX-RS 1.1 APIs or Jersey 2.x with JAX-RS 2.0 APIs. Can you show us your filter, JAX-RS resource and how you call your service?

Comment: See `EDIT 1` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

MY Filter:

```
 @FrontierResponse
 @Provider
 public class PoweredbyResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {
    System.out.println("hell");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");

}
```

}

Resource Class:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FrontierResponse {
}

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("plain")
//@FrontierResponse
public String getMessage() {
    System.out.println("hello world called");
    return "Hello World";
}
```

and finally i call it from a browser
 http:// localhost:4464/plain

Comment: Are you using Jersey 1?
I am stuck at similar issue. Can you please have a look?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283593/containerresponsefilter-is-not-getting-called-by-jersey